# Using Pimple in an MVC project

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I don't want to have to inject the Pimple container into every single model and controller call. I'm a bit confused with how to do this without using some singleton pattern or cross dependencies.

For example, all of my models will extend a base `Model` class. This `Model` class will have the logic for interacting with the database, so it will need to use the `db` service which is an existing PDO connection.

The same logic should apply for my `user` service - which represents the current user of the application. This `user` service should be accessible in all models and controllers without having to inject the container in every single constructor. Again, the `user` service will only be created once per request.

Consider my bootstrapping file (public/index.php):

```
<?php

// load composer
include '../vendor/autoload.php';

// load config definitions
define('db_host', 'localhost');
define('db_port', 3306);
define('db_name', 'rapid');
define('db_username', 'root');
define('db_password', null);

// load container services
$app = new Pimple\Container();
$app['db'] = function () {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=' . db_host . ';port=' . db_port . ';dbname=' . db_name, db_username, db_password);
};
$app['user'] = function ($c) {
    return new App\Models\User($app);
};

// auto-route based on url
new Kjdion84\Rapid\Router($app);

?>
```

You can already see I'm doing something I don't want to do. I'm passing the container in the `User` constructor. I don't want to be passing the container in the constructor of any model that is called. The `User` model extends the `Model` class, which does need to use the `db` service, but like I said, I do not want to be cross-injecting the container.

Next, my `Router` simply calls the appropriate controller/method based on the current URL ("auto-routing", if you will). I would like for all services to be accessible to any controller, again, without passing the container as a parameter in their constructors.

Can someone point me in the right direction here? I think I've read about 1000 different opinions on how to do this, and everyone seems to answer something different.

Comment: Your answer for `I don't want to have to inject the Pimple container into every single model and controller call` is right here `all of my models will extend a base Model class`  PS. I never used Pimple, ... but I know PHP very well.  In other words why cant you put that in the parent controllers __construct, then you just call `parent::__construct()` if you need this Pimple thing when building out the child classes.

Comment: Granted that bakes that dependency into the parent, but the arguments for the DB are already global, and if you are going to use it in `> Pimple container into every single model and controller call` does it really matter as you will have that dependency no matter how you slice it.  It's much better then WET, (write everything twice).  And you could wrap any functionality you want from it in the parent, so all your calls to it are localized in the parent controller where they are easy to change if need be. ON the rare occasion I use 3rd party code I rarely call it directly.

Comment: Then I have to inject that pimple container in a nested pattern. The reason I want the DB in a service container is because I only need the connection to be established once. Sure, I could do it through classes, but then it could be reconnecting several times for no actual purpose other than to avoid code obfuscation.

Comment: Typically only one controller is used per request, so in a way it is already singleton.  For example if functionality is used in multiple controllers it should probably be placed in a model.  Personally I use a sort of singlton for my DB class (its a Multiton, lol, here is a [Example](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Pattern/tree/master/src/evo/pattern/singleton)).  Basically its a class that wraps several singletons (so you can make connections to multiple DBs).  But as I said I don't use this Pimple thing.

Comment: Your question can be interpreted in two ways. So I have to ask: Is your problem that you have to inject the DI container at all, or that you are injecting it in too many instances?

Comment: Because in an MVC structure I would have to pass the container to every single class in the heirarchy. Router -> Controller -> Model